# Why is my button not working in SDL2 using C?

Tags: c, sdl

I want to create a menu using SDL2 in C, and my button is not working when I press it.

What I want to do: When i click on "quitter" I want to leave the game.
[image]

Can someone help me please ?

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0){
        if(ev.type == SDL_QUIT){
            isRunningMain = 0;
            exit(0);

        }else{

           currentImage = mainMenuBg;
           SDL_Rect pos[2];
           int x,y;

          //position of the button to leave the game:
           pos[0].x = 50;
           pos[0].y = 300;
           pos[0].h = 50;
           pos[0].w = 200;

           x = ev.button.x;
           y = ev.button.y;

           if(ev.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
               if(ev.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT){

                if(ev.button.x > 50 && ev.button.x < 170 && ev.button.y > 300 && ev.button.y < 340){
                    SDL_FreeSurface(currentImage);
                }

               }
```

Comment: Hm, according to the dimension of the button, shouldn't it be `ev.button.x > 50 && ev.button.x < 250 && ev.button.y > 300 && ev.button.y < 350`? Did you check, if the event SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN triggers at all on mouseclick? (debug-printf()'s help).

Comment: It's still not working.

SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN doesn't trigger on mouseclick aswell I don't know why

Comment: For debugging reduce the conditions. First just verify that you get any SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN. Then add more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a eg. `cout << "worked";` inside `if(ev.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)` and see if something happens when you click with your left button. If that worked you may also try to put it inside the next too.